# Registering MCE AddIn under existing root menus

Tags: windows-7, mediacenter, windows-media-center

I have written a plugin for Windows 7 Media Center, and I would like to register it to appear under the root "TV" menu.
What do I need to put in the Registration.xml to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe you can...The nearest you can get is the video menu, or create a new, custom menu for your application off the root. Heres a link to the possible settings for integration points [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468319.aspx)